# Questions about removing enrollment from Chromebooks

Tags: discussion, questions

I can see that more and more questions about this topic are posted on Super User or Unix & Linux. It usually goes like this:

> Someone bought a used Chromebook online (eBay, Amazon Marketplace, Craigslist, …) but the device is enrolled to the Chromebook for [Enterprise](https://enterprise.google.com/chrome/devices/#chromebooks) or [Education](https://edu.google.com/k-12-solutions/chromebooks/) environment and cannot be used like a privately owned Chromebook.

For reference here is what the [support page](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/183084?hl=en) says:

> ## Reset a work or school Chromebook
>
> If you're using your Chromebook at work or school, you can't reset it.
>   Ask your administrator to wipe the data on your Chromebook and
>   re-enroll the device on your work or school network.

From my point of view any modification to these devices is very likely to be illegal (as in computer fraud, sabotage or possession of stolen goods), so such questions should better be closed and a **recommendation** be given to the OP **to return the device**.

I'm aware that there is a slight chance of sloppy managed enrolled devices being sold online, enrollment though should be removed when the device can be kept after leaving the organization in question—thus weaken the argument of spying on users. No customer should have to deal with this nor should sites like Stack Exchange and other communities.

In case of an **employee or student of the respective organization** being unhappy with the device being enrolled s/he **should contact the respective administrator or contact person** of the organization instead of asking for hacking advice. A clear distinction between company/organization property and privately owned may also help here understanding why things are as they are.

Cross-posted to Superuser: https://meta.superuser.com/q/12697/252532

Comment: Why illegal? And if some poor dupe has bought something on ebay that was stolen, why penalize them? We're not here to enforce any laws after all.

Comment: Recommending to return the device and request a refund or fix of the problem isn't a penalty from my point of view but constructive feedback so that such devices don't get into average consumers hands. If you have an easier or better solution and have no doubts that this is similar to the hackintosh context, then I'm all ears. What ever solves the problem is good enough for me.

Comment: I'm trying to understand if there is a problem and what that problem would be. I might simply be misunderstanding you here, I don't have any experience with this sort of "enterprise" hardware. However, I do know that we don't enforce laws on SE since i) we're not lawyers and ii) this is an international site and the jurisdiction would be complicated. Where would this be illegal? Where is the OP? Also, what would the answer be? If there is one, we may as well give it. If it's impossible, we can say that. Are you suggesting we consider these questions off topic? On what grounds?

Comment: I'm also not a lawyer. All I know is that [someone](https://coolstar.org/chromebook/) from the hacking community probably knows how but isn't willing to share this info for some reason. Unless someone else knows how (MrChromebox offers Unbricking) and is willing to share then we don't have an answer, thus returning such a device looks like the best advice to me. If it was all fine and dandy it would have probably been posted on https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os by now where you can find all of the other info to dig around in the OS and hardware internals. Sorry that's really all I know.

Comment: Fair enough. And thanks for bringing this up. I'm not trying to argue here, only to understand.

Answer (score 5):

Computer fraud, sabotage? What on earth makes you think that? Buying a second-hand computer is legal! Organizations sell their old hardware, you know. I don't doubt that there are stolen goods on eBay sometimes, but most goods on eBay are perfectly legitimate.

In any case, we [give people the benefit of doubt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice). And [we do not censor questions based on hypothesized security policies](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1278/circumvention-of-security-or-policy).