# How to handle questions with (apparent) malicious intent?

Tags: discussion

A cursory search of metaU&L didn't show anything, so I am going to ask freshly:

Is there a policy with questions that seem to be looking for assistance with malicious code?  I understand that we are supposed to presume good faith, but when someone is asking [how to obfuscate calls to `os.system()` with base64-encoded payloads](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/428561/how-to-execute-a-base64-string) and, when asked about it in a comment, replies (in part) "this is for command execution vulnerability", my presumption of good faith (which was admittedly weak to start with) wanes substantially.

Should such questions be flagged, ignored, or actually answered in a presumption of good faith?

Comment: Relating: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1278/117549

Comment: I was on the fence when I saw that one, too, and any remaining desire to help galloped away when they insulted you. I would ponder a downvote ("how useful is this to anyone else?") and moving on.

Comment: Thanks very kindly for that link; it answers my question well, @JeffSchaller.  And yes, I am refraining from answering it even in light of that answer for the same reason you'd moved on.